# Subdomain on local machine using apache

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, subdomain, localhost, local

On my local network, I have a server that goes by the name of `telly`, and can be connected with locally on `http://telly`.

I am trying to set up a subdomain on that machine, say `sub`. I have added a sites-available record and sites-enabled record labelled `sub.telly`, both contain the following:

ServerName sub.telly
      DocumentRoot /var/www/sub

```
  <Directory /var/www/sub>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
```

but when I try to connect to `http://sub.telly` I get redirected to openDNS guide page, saying the link is not loading properly.

What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, I don't know how your connecting to telly, but I presume it's not via a DNS record coming from open DNS. I assume it's one of the local DNS-like network protocols that shares names of servers so you can locally do things like type in `http://telly/`

So, when you are trying to do sub.telly, that isn't matching with any known local DNS record, so it's going out to opendns and trying to resolve there, which doesn't find anything.

So, I think what you need to do, is setup a DNS record for that? Maybe opendns has an option to setup custom DNS records, and then you can just enter the server IP for that record, and all should navigate through.

If not, you would probably have to setup an actual DNS server somewhere, use that as a referenced server, so that it resolves though.

Comment: of course, cheers